# How to get the number of posts from Relationship field?

Tags: php, wordpress, relationship, advanced-custom-fields

On WordPress site:

– I have custom post type ***“producers”***.

– And i have custom post type ***“movies”***.

– I have relationship field ***“movies_of_this_producer”***.
On the page of edit/creation new post of custom post type “movies” i have this relationship field “movies_of_this_producer”. And in this relationship field “movies_of_this_producer” i can choose a corresponding “producer” post.

As a result, I have the correct relationship between “producers” posts and “movies” posts.

For example, on the site I have post *“Steven Spielberg”* (post of custom post type “producers”), which is associated via relationship field “movies_of_this_producer” with 5 posts: *“Jaws”*, *“Jurassic Park”*, *“Schindler’s List”*, *“The Terminal”*, *“Bridge of Spies”* (5 posts of custom post type “movies”).

Now i need to get for each “producers” post – the number of related “movies” posts (“movies” posts, related with the “producers” post via relationship field “movies_of_this_producer”).

**Question:** How to get the number of related “movies” posts for each “producers” post? What should be the code for this?

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is not a free solution site. If you want help, post the code you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

The relationship field stores the number of rows associated with it as its meta value. Thus if your repeater is named "repeater" and has 2 text rows named "text" with the value of "foo" and "bar", the meta structure would be as follows:

1. `repeater` = "2"

   1. `repeater_0_text` = "foo"
   2. `repeater_1_text` = "bar"

You can either use the default WordPress Codex function of `get_post_meta()` or the ACF specific function `acf_get_metadata()` (which will let you use the field key rather than name).

```
// get the number of repeater rows
$rows = acf_get_metadata( $post_id, 'repeater' );
```